# Explicit cast required for Enumerable.Empty<T>

Tags: c#, arrays, enumerable

Every example I've read so far (google result/stack question) that expalins the use of "Enumerable.Empty" says that i should be able to use it with an array. The VS compiler however, won't allow me to use it unless i explicitly cast it to the array despite defining the type.

Why is this? (I've seen no reference of the cast being required in the ~20 related stack questions or general google results I've looked at)

```
//The internet says this should work, but i get a "Cannot implicitly convert type" error
public byte[] dataA = Enumerable.Empty<byte>();
public string[] dataB = Enumerable.Empty<string>(); 

//Throws no error, but the cast's requirement is never mentioned
public byte[] dataA = (byte[])Enumerable.Empty<byte>();
public string[] dataB = (string[])Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

Comment: Can you post a ling to where it says this should work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You meant [`Array.Empty<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.empty?view=netframework-4.8), not Enumerable:

```
public byte[] dataA = Array.Empty<byte>();
public string[] dataB = Array.Empty<string>();
```

Answer (score 4):

`Enumerable.Empty` generates an empty sequence, not an array.

If you want to convert the sequence to an array then you can call `ToArray`:

```
byte[] dataA = Enumerable.Empty<byte>().ToArray();
string[] dataB = Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToArray();
```

If you really want an empty array then why not say:

```
byte[] dataA = new byte[0];
string[] dataB = new string[0];
```

Your casting might work, but this is very much relying on how `Empty` is implemented. It may just return an empty array, or it may return something else that implements `IEnumerable` but is empty.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use the `ToArray()` Linq method to get an `Array<T>` out of your `IEnumerable<T>`. So, as already said, you *could* create an empty sequence using `Enumerable.Empty<T>` and then convert it to an array.
2. Note that in general the static `Array<T>.Empty` is [recommended way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1825?view=vs-2019) to create an empty array, if you explicitly need one.
3. Avoid those casts `(byte[])` if you can, they will probably bite you hard in the future. Indeed it is not required at all.